# Yii CGridView update

Tags: php, javascript, yii, cgridview

So I gave up on all of the above and decided to move the colums I wanted to show with ajax in a different grid in the main grid but for some reason i get this error:

Trying to get property of non-object

/var/www/html/framework/base/CComponent.php(607) : eval()'d code(1)

```
<?php
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
        'Fund Admin'=>array('/FundAdmin/index/'),
    'Contract Notes'=>array('index'),
    'List',
);

$user = Yii::app()->user;

$this->menu=array(
        array('label'=>'Fund Prices', 'url'=>array('/FundPrice/index'), 'visible'=>$user->checkAccess('listFPrice')),
        array('label'=>'Reports','url'=>array('/FundAdmin/index'), 'visible'=>$user->checkAccess('listReports')),
    array('label'=>'Create Contract Note', 'url'=>array('create'), 'visible'=>$user->checkAccess('createCNote')),
    array('label'=>'Audit Contract Note', 'url'=>array('auditList'), 'visible'=>$user->checkAccess('auditListClient')),
    //array('label'=>'Audit Contract Note Item', 'url'=>array('/ContractNoteItem/auditList'), 'visible'=>$user->checkAccess('auditListClient')),
);

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
$('.search-button').click(function(){
    $('.search-form').toggle();
    return false;
});
$('.search-form form').submit(function(){
    $.fn.yiiGridView.update('contract-note-grid',{
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
});
");
?>



<h1>List Contract Note</h1>

<p>
You may optionally enter a comparison operator (<b>&lt;</b>, <b>&lt;=</b>, <b>&gt;</b>, <b>&gt;=</b>, <b>&lt;&gt;</b>
or <b>=</b>) at the beginning of each of your search values to specify how the comparison should be done.
</p>

<?php echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'search-button')); ?>
<div class="search-form" style="display:none">
<?php $this->renderPartial('_search',array(
    'model'=>$model,
)); ?>
</div><!-- search-form -->

<?php 
//$data=NULL;
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'contract-note-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(           
                array(
                    'name'=>'cn_fund_house_id',
                    'type'=>'raw',
                    'value'=>'$data->cnFundHouse->fh_name',
                ),
                array(
                    'name'=>'contractNoteItems.cni_fund_id',
                    'type'=>'raw',
                    'value'=>'$data->contractNoteItems->f_name', 
        ),
                array(
                    'name'=>'contractNoteItems.cni_isin',
                    'type'=>'raw',
                    'value'=>'$data->contractNoteItems->cni_isin',
                ),

                array(
                    'name'=>'contractNoteItems.cni_client_account_no',
                    'type'=>'raw',
                    'value'=>'$data->contractNoteItems->cni_client_account_no',
                ),

        'cn_investment_date',
        //'cn_settlement_date',

        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                        'deleteConfirmation'=>'Are you sure you want to retire this item?
This item needs to be audited for retirement to take effect.',
            'template'=>'{view}{update}{delete}',
            'buttons'=>array(
                                'view' => array
                (
                                    'label'=>'view',
                                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("contractNoteItem/view",array("id"=>$data->getCNIid($data->id)))',
                                    'visible'=>"Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('editFund')",
                ),
                'update' => array
                (
                                    'label'=>'edit',
                                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("edit",array("id"=>$data["id"]))',
                                    'visible'=>"Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('editFund')",
                ),
                'delete' => array
                (
                                    'label'=>'retire',
                                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("retire",array("id"=>$data["id"]))',
                                    'visible'=>'$data->checkIfRetired($data["id"])',
                )
            )
        ),
    ),
)); 
?>
```

And the particular error comes to the )); right before the php closing tag so I do not understand. If I comment the 'value' for each of the arrays except the first one and the CButtonColumn arrays I don't get the error because I just don't populate the fields with data. So I don't really get why it does this because everything in the models are defined right.

Also note that when I upload the file to my live server I do not get the error but the colums does not show for these colums:

```
array(
                'name'=>'contractNoteItems.cni_fund_id',
                'type'=>'raw',
                'value'=>'$data->contractNoteItems->f_name', 
                 ),
        array(
            'name'=>'contractNoteItems.cni_isin',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>'$data->contractNoteItems->cni_isin',
        ),

        array(
            'name'=>'contractNoteItems.cni_client_account_no',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>'$data->contractNoteItems->cni_client_account_no',
        ),
```

The live server php is 5.3.27 and on my local server is 5.3.3 so I do not know why I get the error on the local. Anyway my question is about the data there not showing and giving me the error on the local server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you issues is in your button area you have lines like this:

```
'visible'=>'$data->checkIfRetired($data["id"])',
```

However `$data` should be an object not an array. Try changing it to:

```
'visible'=>'$data->checkIfRetired($data->id)',
```

In reality though you should need to pass any data to functions like `checkIfRetired` since it is already an instance. In the function you should just be able to use the value `$this->id` instead of having to pass it.

Answer (score 0):

The `value` elements for your columns are the problem. When the `value` element of a column is not specified, Yii checks whether the object exists before getting the value of the desired attribute. Your `value` elements do not have this check hence the error.

For simplicity in your code, there is no need to add the `value` and `type` elements for some columns. As such your code becomes

```
'columns'=>array(
    ...
    'contractNoteItems.cni_fund_id',
    'contractNoteItems.cni_isin',
    'contractNoteItems.cni_client_account_no',
    ...
)
```

For more information, see [CGridView.columns](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#columns-detail)